# re.match never returns None?

Tags: python, python-re

I've browsed google and stack for a while in search of an answer but everyone seems to be facing re.match always returning None, while I have the exact opposite issue: it never returns None, even when there's no match.
My apologies if this sounds simple to you but I've been stuck on this for a while and it's driving me crazy, so I would really be grateful if someone could come to my rescue.

Here's the little snippet of code that's buggering me:

```py
try:
    pat = r'(?P<days>(\d+)(d))? ?(?P<hours>(\d+)(h))? ?(?P<minutes>(\d+)(m))?'
    match = re.match(pat, arg)
except:
    pat = r'(?P<days>(\d+)(\sd))? ?(?P<hours>(\d+)(\sh))? ?(?P<minutes>(\d+)(\sm))?'
    match = re.match(pat, arg)
```

It does the job, matches the pattern I'm looking for, but I can't find a way to filter out the unmatched args.

Unfortunately I can't post images as I'm newly registered but here's what happens:
[image]

The documentation says that in those cases, match should be None, but I can't get it to work correctly.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: All your groups are optional so of course it'll match the empty string.

Comment: Your pattern is compatible with an empty match, i.e. matching ``''``.

Comment: You shouldn't use == to test for None

Comment: By the way -- please post your errors as copied-and-pasted text rather than images or screenshots. See [Why not upload images of code or errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) on [meta], which is where we discuss and decide on our rules. Text can be searched; other people can copy-and-paste to test it; problems caused by lookalike characters can be addressed, and it doesn't cause the problems that images do with accessibility tools, displays with a different resolution or color scheme, etc.

Comment: @Aplet123 and Mister thank you! I need to work on that pattern.
The == is a noob attempt at "what if?" but I initially used "Is None"
Charles, good point, I will do so from now on. Thanks!